# Replace spaces when surrounded by numeric values, but not by alpha-character

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

In a fixed width file containing only alpha-numeric characters, I would like to replace the white spaces between alpha-character and numeric fields (including signed decimal, but not scientific notation) as well as numeric and numeric fields while leaving the white spaces between alpha-character values.

I am aware of the `FIELDWIDTHS` option using `awk` but the type of files I have have too many fields with too many unique structures to make a generalization.

Here is a toy example:

```
708 447 4797 JOHN SMITH 18000
```

Needs to be formatted as follows:

```
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
```

Looking for any portable solution using `sed`, `perl`, `awk` etc.

EDIT:

To clarify the question and generalize for better overall usability, here are more lines to test the solutions with. Please continue with the assumption that any alpha-characters that have a space are indeed meant to be kept together (i.e. assume no occurrences of `Bob Jones Chuck Smith`).

```
708 447 4797 JOHN SMITH 18000
708 447 4797 JOHN SMITH    18000
708  447  4797  JOHN SMITH  18000
708 -3.00 4797 JOHN SMITH 18000
```

Should result in:

```
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|-3.00|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
```

Comment: If everything is fixed width, the safest way is to read the line, bust up the fields based on the widths you know, and then rewrite the fields back out with new delimiters.

Comment: @AndyLester As specified in the question, I unfortunately cannot rely on the files to have the same fwf structure, and the number of fields prohibits efficient reconstruction for each one.

Comment: What if you have `123 Bob Jones Chuck Smith 456`? Are Bob and Chuck different people?

Comment: When you say "character" above, do you mean "alphabetic" or something else (e.g. does it include characters like `.`, `$`, `[`, etc.)? When you say "numeric" do you mean "whole number" or something else (e.g. does it include numbers like `-8`, `0.5` and `3e7`)? That one line you provided really is a pretty hopeless sample input set to test against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/([^[:alpha:]]) +| +([^[:alpha:]])/\1|\2/g' file
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|-3.00|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
```

---

**EDIT:** Using `gnu-awk`:

```
awk -v OFS='|' 'BEGIN { 
  FPAT="[^[:alpha:] ]+[[:alpha:]]+( +[[:alpha:]]+)*"
} {$1=$1} 1' file
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|-3.00|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
```

Comment: Great, thank you. How would the solution differ if there were multiple spaces between fields? (see edited question)

Comment: Same, in Perl `perl -pe 's/[^a-z]\K +| +(?=[^a-z])/|/gi'`

Comment: that won't actually work in general to do what the OP says they want `replace the white spaces between character and numeric fields as well as numeric and numeric fields while leaving the white spaces between character values`. It just produces the expected output from the given sample input but will fail with other inputs (e.g. replace "4797" with "BILL"). The OP should have done a better job of thinking about what their input might be instead of just providing 1 line with just 1 possible case in it.

Comment: Probably: `sed -r 's/([[:alpha:]]) +([[:digit:]])|([[:digit:]]) +(.)/\1\3|\2\4/g'` would be better but I can check this after seeing more input samples.

Comment: Beats me, I have only a vague idea what the question is. What's a "character" field? It probably doesn't contain digits but idk if there's any other characters it can/can't contain. What's a "numeric" field? It may be all digits or may contain negative signs or decimal points or.....

Comment: @mkemp6: May I know what's wrong with the answer? Even your updated question's output is correctly coming with the `sed` commands I provided.

Comment: @EdMorton: I have also added an `awk` answer here. OP has also edited the question to provide more sample data.

Comment: Yup I had a very similar gawk solution in mind: `FPAT='[^[:alpha:][:space:]]+|[[:alpha:]]+[[:space:]]*[[:alpha:]]*'` but yours is better as I was assuming a single space inside the alphabetic fields.

Comment: ++ for "<<< "  for the trip down "olde tyme shell" lane :-) (was in the original response).

Comment: @anubhava I had simplified my question to try it to make it more useful to the SO community, the perl script dealt with some irregularities -- but I do like your awk +1

Answer (score 2):

This is all that is necessary

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = '708 447 4797 JOHN SMITH 18000';
$s =~ s/ (?<=\d) \h+ | \h+ (?=\d) /|/axg;
say $s;
```

**output**

```
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
```

Comment: Does `(?<=\d)` ... `(?=\d)` make this match more reliably?  (*i.e.* the use of "zero-width positive look-behind" in general) or is it a choice made for readability documentation ?

Comment: @G.Cito: It's similar to `\d` ... `\d`, except that it isn't part of the matched string. In the case of a substitution, as here, without using look-behind and look-ahead you would have to capture the digit and replace it using `$1` or `$2` in the substitution string. But there's no simple way to tell which of the alternations matched, so we can't know whether the replacement text should be `$1|` or `|$2` without using an executable replacement. Also, if the string is `AAA 9 AAA` then ` (\d) \h+ | \h+ (\d)` will match the space followed by `9` first, but the second space won't be found.

Comment: Excellent explanation. There is often much more thought required than at first seems necessary in order to for make a regexe robust *vis-a-vis* pesky and constantly unpredictable text. They are deceptively simple but powerful: towhit [Jamie Zawinsky] (http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski). ;-)

Answer (score 2):

With this regex:

```
(?<=\d)[[:blank:]]+(?!$)|[[:blank:]]+(?=\d)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uK9vD0/2)

Perl demo:

```
$ cat /tmp/nums.txt
708 447 4797 JOHN SMITH 18000
708 447 4797 JOHN SMITH    18000
708  447  4797  JOHN SMITH  18000
708 -3.00 4797 JOHN SMITH 18000

$ perl -pe 's/(?<=\d)[[:blank:]]+(?!$)|[[:blank:]]+(?=\d)/|/g' /tmp/nums.txt
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
708|-3.00|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other ways through Perl,

```
$ echo '708 447 4797 JOHN SMITH 18000' | perl -pe 's/(?<=[A-Za-z])\h+(?=[A-Za-z])(*SKIP)(*F)|\h/|/g' 
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
```

OR

```
$ echo '708 447 4797 JOHN SMITH 18000' | perl -pe 's/(?<![A-Za-z])\h+|\h+(?![A-Za-z])/|/g' 
708|447|4797|JOHN SMITH|18000
```

Comment: I get `Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<=[A-Za-z])h+(?=[A-Za-z])(* <-- HERE SKIP)(*F)|h/ at -e line 1.` from version `v5.8.4 built for sun4-solaris-64int`. Different error messages from other versions too.

Answer (score 1):

While I like anubhava's sed solution, it seems more obvious to me to convert all spaces into your new separator, then identify what needs to be switched back.  The following produces the output you want from your sample data and also adapts to Ed Morton's concern about handling nearby alpha fields:

```
sed -r 's/ +/|/g; s/([[:alpha:]])\|([[:alpha:]])/\1 \2/g'
```

It has the advantage of being a little shorter and easier to read.  (Okay, not much easier. It's still sed, after all.)

One possible concern would be that this does not *preserve* whitespace inside text fields.  That is, `JOHN  SMITH` would be converted to `JOHN SMITH`.

A way to avoid this would be this:

```
sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]) +/\1|/g; s/ +([[:digit:]])/|\1/g'
```

which I believe is just about equivalent to anubhava's solution except that it matches your requirements of separating fields around numeric content rather than around non-alphabetic content.

You'd think that this sort of thing would be easy in `awk` as well, but as it turns out, awk's `sub()` and `gsub()` do not support backreferences.  If you happen to be using `gawk` however, the `gensub()` function may work:

```
gawk '{gsub(/ +/,"|"); print gensub(/([[:alpha:]])\|([[:alpha:]])/, "\\1 \\2", "g", $0);}
```

or

```
gawk '{print gensub(/([[:digit:]]) +/,"\\1|","g",gensub(/ +([[:digit:]])/,"|\\1","g",$0));}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what occurred to me as an admittedly quick lazy stab at it:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d)\h+|\h+(\d)/$1|$2/g' <<< "123 49 5440 G.  Cito 1967 23456" 
123|49|5440|G.  Cito|1967|23456
```

I read it as follows: "Replace a digit followed by more than one horizontal space OR more than one horizontal space followed by a digit; with the original digit and |".  It would preserve multiple spaces in alphabetical part of the string but would put "`|`" at the beginning if there were space before the `123` in this case.

**NB**: the quick/easy approach above in this response has an issue - see Borodin's response to my question about his/her solution. The fix is to use (as Borodin notes)  `(?<=)` `(?=)` [zero-width look around](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) which allows the expression inside (`\d`) to work as a "boundary" and not get included in the match so `$1`, `$2`, `\1` and `\2` are not needed and only the horizontal space is replaced with `|`.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\d)\h+|\h+(?=\d)/|/g' <<<"9 AAA 9 AAA 54 G. Cito 1967 123"
9|AAA|9|AAA|54|G. Cito|1967|123
```

Thanks @Borodin!